# iOS CoreData Schema Design Guidance

Tags: ios, core-data, database-schema

Any suggestions on how I should design a scalable database schema for a messaging system.  This messaging system will NOT have any attachments.  I would like to use APNS notifications to inform the user of new incoming messages.   Kind of like facebook messaging but without attachments.

How should I set up the entities/tables? Relationships? APNS Integration?  If someone has done this in the past, it'll be nice to see graphic layout?

I plan on using Core Data with StackMob (Remote Database).

Thanks!

Comment: Does your DB in the app matter so much? The server providing the persistence of all accounts and messages is more important. The app should store very little data really and it's all downloaded from the server... Your DB will likely reflect the objects held on the server.

Comment: Correct. But I still need to configure the DB. Make tables and etc. what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're planning for the app to know 1 user, their contacts and the messages sent to + received from those contacts... I'm also guessing that that user logs out you'll delete all data for the old user from the app and download new data from the server for the new user.

I probably wouldn't worry about having an object for the current user, it doesn't offer much utility. I'd probably use user defaults to store the user identity and have an avatar image on disk at a known location.

For the model I'd probably have 2 entities:

1. `Contact`
2. `Message`

`Contact` has the name, id, avatar file name, the date of the most recent message (and maybe the first ever message) and a relationship to `Message` (one to many)
`Message` has the message text, the sent date and a flag identifying the message as sent / received

With this super simple data model you can easily download and store contact information without needing to download all the messages. You can list the contacts for the user and you know which you most recently received messages from (or sent to). When you need to you can download and fill in the most recent messages for a specified user.

As your server holds all the data, if you find that you need to change the data model your upgrade path is simple: delete the old DB file, create a new one and download the data again. You should never have more data than you need on the device and you should purge old messages (and not show them on screen unless requested) periodically.

The server and RESTful interface are still the more important bit to define well. I'd use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) to interact with the server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on Avatar image?

Comment: What it is? Google and check the first hit.